# using a form with php sessions(I want to take the username from the form and pass to $_session[user]

Tags: php, mysql, session

I would like to know how to take information from a form and enter it into a session. I can check for sessions, close sessions, but cannot see how to take information from a form (everyone of them use $username variables which is not what I want, I would like to have $_SESSION[user] = username (from form).Sorry to ask, but I have spent ages trying to find an example to work on

HTML Form is simple:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="POST" action="authorise.php">
Username: <input type ="text" name="username"/><br/>
Password: <input type ="password" name="password"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

php authorisation:

```
session_start();
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_site","root","black$23");
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE LOWER(username)=:username";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':username',strtolower ($_POST['username']));
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{

    $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    require('blowfish.php');
    require('bcrypt.class.php');
    //require('bcrypt.class2.php');
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(4);
    if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['password'],$row['password']))
    {

        echo"logged in!!";
        header("Location: .");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you want it in your session? the form is a POST so you have to pull out the $_POST that is sent? are you trying to put the post inside your session? im confused.

Comment: `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user']` ?

Comment: I am trying to take the username from the form and put it in the session. I just want to use it so that I can stop people without a login getting access to any of the web pages.

Comment: I get the following error when using $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];   Notice: Undefined index: username.

Comment: where is your session? where are you putting that line `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];`? can you edit your post with where its put?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

or

```
$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

if you want to use all of the information from the form... but I would not recommend that.

Comment: I get the following error when using $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];   Notice: Undefined index: username

Answer (score 0):

The key is to match the `name=` attribute from (for e.g.) `<input>` elements in the form, to the `$_POST['varname']` values in the receiving PHP file. The `name` attribute becomes the **variable's name** once posted over to the PHP side. The contents of the field are the variable's value.

Then, to create a session variable from the POSTed value.

For example:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="authorise.php">
    Username: <input type ="text" name="username"/><br/>
    Password: <input type ="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $un = $_POST['username'];
    $pw = $_POST['password'];

    if ($pw == 'admin'){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $un;
    }
```

NOTE: Remember to sanitize anything a user types in.